# Is it okay to Except with error on GRPC Deadline Exceed error and retry connection from client side?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am a beginner in golang and trying to implement client side streaming grpc in go language.
Error:  **rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded**
On hitting the timeout, deadline exceeded error, can i just except and create the grpc channel again.I am using a grpc client side streaming system with a client timeout of 30Seconds.

What could be the reasons for getting this error? Do i need to restart the server also if i am hitting the deadlineExceeded case. I sometimes noticed that the server become inactive during that time.

```
func LiveData(client pb.GRPCGatewayServiceClient, grpclivereqdata []*pb.LiveRequest) string 
{

ctx, cancel:= context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
defer cancel()
stream, err := client.LiveData(ctx)
start_time_liv := ((time.Now().UnixNano()) / 1000000)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(" client.LiveData(ctx) : %v", err)
    return "err"
}
for _, val := range grpclivereqdata {
    fmt.Println("STREAM :", val.PatchId, ":", val.Seq, ":", ((time.Now().UnixNano()) / 1000000))
    stream.Send(val)
}
in, err := stream.CloseAndRecv()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error when closing the stream and receiving the response: %v %v ms %v\n", err, in, ((time.Now().UnixNano())/1000000)-start_time_liv)
    return "err"
}
return in.LiveResp
}
```

Comment: why is this tagged python?

Comment: You are setting a 30s timeout with `context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)` so after 30s the grpc call will terminate with the error you are seeing. You can increase or remove the timeout by changing the way the context is created. Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for?